# Calculating required sample size

Tags: sample

I am currently using a formula I got from a Qualtrics blog post to calculate the sample I require for a survey for the mean to be meaningful/reflect the population mean, as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7KAm.jpg

My survey has a large Std.dev (1.8), which I use instead of assuming a 0.5 Std.dev. This formula does not seem to take into consideration the population size (>10 000), however.

Is there an alternate formula to calculate required sample size with a known population size (but an unknown population std.dev)?

Answer (score 2):

Population size is irrelevant unless the sample is a large portion of the population, which is clearly not the case here.  There is a finite population correction:
$FPC = \sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}$

where N is population size and n is sample size, but this is so close to 1 in your case that it can be ignored.

Comment: Out of interest and possible future application, what would one then do with the FPC value (which in my case is 0,98)?

Comment: One would multiply the sample size by its inverse.

Comment: So n * (1/FPC)?